# str() not returning string in my function

Tags: python, string, int

So I've defined a recursive function numToBaseB that converts a given number in base ten into any other base between 2 and 10. The desired output is a string, but for some reason I keep getting an int.

```
def numToBaseB(num, b):
    if num == 0:
        return ''
    elif b > 10 or b < 2:
        return "The base has to be between 2 and 10"
    else:
        return numToBaseB(num // b, b ) + str(num % b)
```

So for me:
`numToBaseB(4, 2)` would return

> > > 100

instead of the desired output:

> > > '100'

Comment: That's not possible. If you're `print`ing out the result, then this is the intended behavior, as the quotes are only shown in the console to help you see what the variable is.

Comment: Yeah, Tim Pietzcker pointed out the same thing, thanks though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is working as designed:

```
>>> numToBaseB(1024,2)
'10000000000'
>>> numToBaseB(4,2)
'100'
```

Of course, if you do `print(numToBaseB(4,2))`, the quotes will not be displayed.

Comment: I'm not sure the original design included that converting `0` to a base should give an empty string instead of `"0"`. It's working as coded, but they always do :-D

Comment: Yes that's part of it, thanks for making sure though!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have quotes though, you can always do this:

```
print (" ' "+numToBase(4,2)+" ' ")
```

But in the program, if you use str() anyways, it will be treated as string ofcourse.

:)

Edit: typing on phone, so sorry for this madness :(

Comment: You can just use `repr()` which adds quotes around the string :)

Comment: @mnunberg woah! Completely forgot about that one O.o